# Google Earth Engine: Linear Regression problem to download the image

Tags: google-earth-engine, regression, savi

I made this code to get a Linear Regression using the function SAVI in my own collection but it is not working.

Does anyone know why?

```
 // Simple regression of year versus NDVI.

  // Define the start date and position to get images covering SatgeArea,
  // Bolivia, from 2000-2010.
  var start = '2000-01-01';
  var end = '2014-12-31';

  var region = table


  // Filter to Collection
  // time of year to avoid seasonal affects, and for each image create 
  the bands
  // we will regress on:
  // 1. A 1, so the resulting array has a column of ones to capture the 
  offset.
  // 2. Fractional year past 2000-01-01.
  // 3. SAVI.
  // 4. Mask Clouds
  var col = imageCollection
    .sort('system:time_start')
    .filterBounds(region)
    .map(function(image) {
      var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
      var yearOffset = date.difference(ee.Date(start), 'year');
      var savi = image.expression(
        '(1 + L) * float(nir - red)/ (nir + red + L)', {
          'nir': image.select('B4'),
          'red': image.select('B3'),
          'L': 0.5
        });
      var mask = image.select(['cfmask']).neq((1, 2, 3, 4));
      return

      ee.Image(1).addBands(yearOffset).addBands(savi).toDouble().updateMask(mask);
    });

  print(col)
  // Convert to an array. Give the axes names for more readable code.
  var array = col.toArray();
  var imageAxis = 0;
  var bandAxis = 1;

  // Slice off the year and ndvi, and solve for the coefficients.
  var x = array.arraySlice(bandAxis, 0, 2);
  var y = array.arraySlice(bandAxis, 2);
  var fit = x.matrixSolve(y);

  // Get the coefficient for the year, effectively the slope of the long-term
  // NDVI trend.
  var slope = fit.arrayGet([1, 0]).clip(region);

  Map.addLayer(slope);

  // Export the image, specifying scale and region.
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: slope,
    description: 'SAVI_slope_jan',
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9,
    region: table
  });
```

Im using my own collection (images from `LE7_SR` and `LT5_SR`) and my own geometry (table).
I can map the result (slope) but I cannot download and if I try with a normal collection (`ee.ImageCollection`) I can. Does anyone know why I cannot download the image from my own collection?

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is the resulting layer not right?

Comment: I cannot download the image (there are no errors). Basically it is downloading the image for ages.

Comment: I can Map.addLayer("result") but I cannot download it.

Comment: Use `Export.image`.  If it fails, report back with the error message.  If not, wait...

Comment: I am using Export.image.toDrive and it fails.

Comment: I mean, it does not fails but it is downloading for 20h which it is not normal.

Comment: Is the download (i.e. from Drive to your PC) taking 20h or the Export (i.e. from GEE to Drive)? I've had exports take in more than 48 hours, depending on the area and complexity of the calculation. If the Export was successfull but the download takes this long the issue is with your connection - not the Earth Engine.

Comment: The problem remains in the export from GEE to Drive. Thank you

Comment: Now it is giving me this error when tries to export from GEE to Drive.

Error: matrixSolve cannot solve underdetermined system.